# SQL Server as Database Backend for Ionic?

Tags: sql-server, angularjs, ionic-framework

How do I connect to SQL Server as a backend for Ionic mobile apps?

Comment: you cant directly access `SQL server` from your ionic app, or any database for that matter. you should implement a $http api . However if you want to store some simple data, you could try a lightweight data store  `sqlite`, `ng-storage`  etc..

Comment: what is the maximum size of sqlite database ?? is it professionnal ! .. @sameera207

Comment: its totally depending on how you want to user the data. I use `ng-storage` to store non-trivial data. (ex: last browse position of the user, even if this fails, I can load the details from the server, its not critical), But most of the time, your app should run with a server database and connected via an http API

Answer (score 4):

Typically one would create an HTTP API (most likely using REST) that would serve as the interface to the database. This API would be developed in a server side technology of choice: node, ASP.NET, php, etc.  The API would connect and communicate with SQL Server by executing T-SQL queries or stored procedures.

Your API would be called by your angular application using the $http service provided by angular.

Additional reference materials:

[Angular $http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#!)

[T-SQL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189826%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)